# Display a PDF from server with CFURLRef

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

Hi I am trying to display a pdf from server , this code load pdf from Resource :

```
CFURLRef pdfURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), CFSTR("paper.pdf"), NULL, NULL);
pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
    CFRelease(pdfURL);
```

but when I try to change the code like this :

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someurl.com/file.pfd"];

   CFURLRef pdfURL = CFURLGetBaseURL((CFURLRef) url);
```

my app does crash with (SIDKILL) error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CFURLGetBaseURL` will get the base of the, not one pointing to your PDF.
Try this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someurl.com/file.pfd"];
CFURLRef pdfURL =(CFURLRef) url;
```

SIDKILL ( I think you meant SIGKILL) would mean that you could be calling a instance which no longer exists. Post more code if problem still persists, also enable zombies.

Comment: I follow this sample code :
[link](https://github.com/brow/leaves) 
in this sample code application loads a PDF file from the resource and I try to load it from a server . The compiler gives me `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`